# Can't we inject component directly to App.js?

Tags: reactjs, src

I am newbie to web development.After I had finished html,css and js(basic things) I recently have started learning react js. On my first project setup src folder I see index.js and app.js files. Why we need index.js  files here? Can't we inject component directly to App.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` is generally used to say communicate _this is the highest level within this directory/hiearchy. Index is the entry point to your application where it's bootstrapped in the DOM. `App` is just a component like any other component. You could call it anything, e.g., `Root`, `ComponentNotNamedApp`, etc.

You don't *need* both, but it keeps the index file clean without adding in a bunch of component code. In `App`, you may be wrapping things with contexts, them providers, adding in other components, etc.

My app uses redux, so all that's in index is this,

```
ReactDOM.render(
    // redux stuff
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```